# Unable to create an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an image on the page using JavaScript, however even the alert('This function works!') does not work!
I have no idea why it doesn't work, Help please!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
        function loadImages() {    
            myImage = new Image();
            myImage.src = "./images/A_01.png";
            document.createElement(myImage);
            document.alert('This function works!');
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="text-align: center">
            <button>
                <img src="images/K_01.png" onclick="loadImages()" alt="button" style="vertical-align: bottom">
                 onvert
            </button>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `language="javascript"` - that attribute is deprecated. Just omit it!

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's the least of his problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never append the image to the DOM. Use `appendChild()` for that:

```
function loadImages(){ 

  myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = "./images/A_01.png";

  document.body.appendChild( myImage );

}
```

---

`createElement()` actually will create a new element. You can use this as an alternative to your `new Image()` constructor. It, however, does **not** add the created element to the DOM. Hence it will remain invisible until you do add it to the DOM.

- [MDN on `createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

Answer (score 0):

Don't put an image in the button element. Add CSS to it to apply the image as a background:

```
 <button style="background-image:url(path/to/image.png" id="btn" alt="button">
```

I've updated your javascript to attach a listener unobstrusively, ensured the element is appended to the body, and called `alert` properly:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', loadImages);

function loadImages(){ 
  myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = "./images/A_01.png";
  document.body.appendChild(myImage);
  alert('This function works!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Q5UA/